Angular and ASP.NET Core 8 project : Docker launch: The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event
My apologies - this is my first time trying to use this this way - usually I'll just build using a ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project and build out the UI.
I tried building with the Angular and ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio 2022 Community. I set up the project to use Docker for the SQL Server using .NET 8.
Every time I go to run the project, which I haven't modified much if at all, I get the errors

Debugging Error : the program to Debug cannot be found in the container

and

The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event.  Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.

Here is my docker file:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS with-node
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

FROM with-node AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["myApp1.Server/myApp1.Server.csproj", "myApp1.Server/"]
COPY ["myapp1.client/myapp1.client.esproj", "myapp1.client/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./myApp1.Server/myApp1.Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/myApp1.Server"
RUN dotnet build "./myApp1.Server.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./myApp1.Server.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myApp1.Server.dll"]

Here is my Program file:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");

app.Run();

I'm taking a guess that I cannot just run this off the shelf to generate the "weather forecast" response and something is missing.  I appreciate feedback (I think and hope)
I'm simply trying to run the project on first load.  I've tried going through Stack Overflows but to no avail
